# Can I convert freewheel hub to use cassette?

Tags: repair

I'm converting a 1989 Trek 830/Antelope MTB to a commuter and it has a freewheel. Can I convert it to a cassette with the same hub?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see a question here. Stackexchange is not a forum where a generalised discussion starter like this is appropriate. Could you possibly edit this down to a specific, answerable question?

Comment: Why? You can still get decent freewheels pretty cheaply (10-20 USD).

Comment: Depends what you mean by same hub.  Also I agree with Batman in that 7 and even 8 speed freewheels are inexpensive.  What is your goal in moving to a cassette?  How many cogs does your current freewheel on your MTB have?

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible. You need to replace the entire hub, and the easiest way to do that is to replace the entire wheel.

Comment: Also, with a 1989 era bike that probably means spreading the frame so it can accept a modern hub.

Comment: Modern MTB hubs which don't use thru-axles are likely to be 135mm OLD, while "retro" MTBs may be 130mm at the rear... Such a frame is unlikely to be using disc brakes, so there's no reason not to use a 130mm "road" hub.